# OpenGL - What role does a vertex normal play in point light calculations?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In per-fragment point lighting, what role role does a vertex normal play in point light calculations?

My understanding is that the brightness of a fragment is based solely on it's distance from the light source, and that a directional vector would be irrelevant.

Example Shader

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec3 u_LightPos;

varying vec3 v_Position;
varying vec4 v_Color; 
varying vec3 v_Normal; 

void main()
{
    float distance = length(u_LightPos - v_Position);
    vec3 lightVector = normalize(u_LightPos - v_Position); 
    float diffuse = max(dot(v_Normal, lightVector), 0.1);
    diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.25 * distance * distance)));
    gl_FragColor = v_Color * diffuse;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using Lambertian diffuse lighting. In this case, the surface brightness is proportional to the intensity of incoming light (the inverse square term in your equation) and additionally to the cosine of the angle between the surface normal and the direction of the incoming light (the dot product in your equation).

This makes a lot of sense after some thought. Consider the two extremes: you would expect a piece of paper held perpendicular to the beam of a flashlight to appear much brighter than one held parallel to the beam.

For more information, see [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance#Use_in_computer_graphics) of the relevant wikipedia page.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on it. Is there an alternate point lighting algorithm independent to direction?

Comment: I've never used one. It would be sort of strange, as adjusting the viewing angle of the object wouldn't affect the surface light intensity. You could always remove the dot product term and see how it looks without it.

Comment: Ah ok. So it's very standard to use Lambertian, thanks.

Comment: Hold on, but this is for a one time pre-pass to calculate a lightmap. I'm implementing it in the shader first to get the effect I'm after, and then will mimic it in c# to dump to a texture. So, the direction actually is irrelevant.

Comment: Actually.. scratch that, I'm getting confused between camera direction and vertex direction.